# remove junk characters in timestamp in BQ table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Experts im getting junk characters in my timestamp, while to load in bq it failed. i tried regexp with following format
REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'[^[a-z,A-Z,0-9]]*',' ').it behave weird

as is :2022-06-28T06^%^3A55^%^3A01.452Z
expected:2022-06-28T06:55:01.452Z

Please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: For this specific case,  **SELECT REPLACE('2022-06-28T06^%^3A55^%^3A01.452Z', '^%^3A', ':')** would be enough. If you want to more generalized solution, you need to provide more samples from your data.

Comment: thanks for your reply..  for this specific case this will work..  i want to use something like regexp command it should suitable for all the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you sample in bq **select REGEXP_REPLACE('2022-06-28T06^%^3A55^%^3A01.452Z',"[\D\W]{3}[\d\w]{2}",':')**

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE('2022-06-28T06^%^3A55^%^3A01.452Z',"[\\D\\W]{3}[\\d\\w]{2}",':')